# Display the borders of more than one city in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

If I click on a city's name in Google Maps, the area of the city will be highlighted, its borders are shown in red, and the view adjusted to center on the city. Is there a way to select more than one city and in such a way that the borders for both are shown?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible to achieve in Google Maps. But you can play with **[Google Map Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)**

[image]

[image: 0]

[image: 0]